# After form submit, scroll to form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, laravel

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate (i searched everywhere for a possible solution) but i just have to know how to use a jquery code after submitting a form in Laravel.

FYI: I am using Laravel and i use a Redirect::back() when form credentials are correct.

Here's my Controller code used when submitting form:

```
public function store()
    {
        $user = array(
            'voornaam'          => Input::get('voornaam'),
            'achternaam'        => Input::get('achternaam'),
            'email'             => Input::get('email'),
            'telefoonnummer'    => Input::get('telefoonnummer'),
            'bedrijfsnaam'      => Input::get('bedrijfsnaam'),
            'adres'             => Input::get('adres'),
            'opmerking'         => Input::get('opmerking'), 
            'titel'             => Input::get('paginanaam'),
            'datum'             => Input::get('dedatum'),
            'personen'          => Input::get('personen'),
        );
        $data = $user;

        $rules = array(
            'voornaam'      => 'required',
            'achternaam'    => 'required',
            'email'         => 'required',
            'adres'         => 'required',
            'bedrijfsnaam'  => 'required',
            'datum'         => 'required',
        );

        $messages = array(
            'voornaam.required'     => 'Vul a.u.b. uw voornaam in.',
            'achternaam.required'   => 'Vul a.u.b. uw achternaam in.',
            'email.required'        => 'Vul a.u.b. uw emailadres in.',
            'adres.required'        => 'Vul a.u.b. uw factuuradres in.',
            'bedrijfsnaam.required' => 'Vul a.u.b. uw bedrijfsnaam in.',
            'datum.required'        => 'Selecteer a.u.b. een datum.',
        );

        if(Input::get('spamcheck'))
        {
            return 'Stop spamming please.';
        }

        $validation = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
        if ( $validation->fails() )
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
        } else {
            if(Input::get('kopie') === 'ja') {
                Mail::send();

            } else {
                Mail::sendothermail();
            }

        return Redirect::back();
    }
}
```

I deleted some unneccesary code from this controller (fyi) so you won't get distracted from my problem. When a user submits the form and it has errors, the errors are displayed at the top of the page. But, i would like to make something like: when a user submits the form, and credentials are ok, it reloads the page and should scroll to the form and hides the form and displays a success message instead of the form.

IF this is a duplicate for a similair problem, please let me know.

Comment: Are you using ajax to submit the form?

Comment: No just regular php. (in Laravel)

Comment: So I guess there are two ways to solve this: 1) redirect to the page and use a hash fragment to move the page to the right place, or 2) add something in session to say that the form was submitted correctly, then in your view, check the session variable and do whatever you want based on that (inject some JS that uses `window.scrollTo()`, display a message, etc.)

Comment: @alexrussell Could you an example of what you mean at 1) ? I will try to do something you say at 2)  ;)

Comment: Actually what i meant by #1 is basically @Thisis's answer - basically instead of using `Redirect::back()` use another redirect method to a known URL. For example if you are using named routes: `Redirect::to(URL::route('my.route').'#form')`

Comment: Ha, and what i meant by #2 is pretty much @Brian's answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon successful validation return to your view with session flash data to perform `if success load js`

**Controller**

`return Redirect::back()->with('success');`

**View** - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhmbyphq/1)

```
@if(Session::get('success'))

    <script>

         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#form").offset().top
         }, 2000);

         window.setTimeout(function(){
             $('#form').hide().next('#success').show();
         }, 1500);

    </script>

@endif
```

Comment: Trying to make this work! For what i can read of it, it is what i am looking for. I'll post if it is successfull ;) Thanks for now!

Comment: I'm getting a "TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined scrollTop: $("#aanmelden").offset().top " in my console log.

Comment: that can be because of a faulty selector or if `#aanmelden` is not displayed.

Comment: Make sure that the div that contains the form (or the form itself) has an id of `form`, and make sure you are using jQuery.

Comment: Ofcourse, my bad! forgot that the page was reloaded after submit, so added a `$(document).ready`

Comment: Thanks Brian and @alexrussel for helping. If there's anything i can do in return .. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Give the element that contains either the form+error or the succes message a 'name' attribute, say 'form'. Then, don't use Redirect:back(), but instead Redirect to the page with #form behind it, for example 'index.php#form'.
JavaScript would offer some more options.

Comment: I don't know if you are familliar with Laravel, but the redirecting isn't done with index.php etc. It's with routes etc. But anyways, when i do that it just does nothing. It wont submit, i can click all i want. Or i am doing something wrong, coudl you post an example?